# Why isn't my KendoDatePicker value being found using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I have a model I am building using the Kendo DatePicker values from my MVC page:

```
    searchModel.FilingDateEnd = kendo.toString($("#FilingDateEnd").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

However, if I type in the value rather than clicking the calendar and selecting the date, it does not get a value here.  How can I get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you can simply use the value of the control to get the date entered, either via typing OR date select:

```
searchModel.FilingDateEnd = $("#FilingDateEnd").val();
```